# Llenado automatico de textbox con datos tipo String con JavaScript y JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

Tengo un problema con un llenado que hago con JavaScript a la hora de la funcionalidad de un formulario en el que hago una gestion en la base de datos, tiene los botones de insertar, eliminar, modificar y mostrar. Cuando quiero eliminar o modificar uso una funcion que me selecciona los datos de la base y me los llena dentro de su respectivo textbox.

Mi problema es que a la hora de que un dato tipo String tenga un espacio, directamente no me llena ningún textbox.

Este es mi método de llenado.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <script>
            function llenar(codigo,nombre,precio,pro)
                {
                    document.getElementById("idd").value=codigo;
                    document.getElementById("nombree").value=nombre;
                    document.getElementById("precioo").value=precio;
                    document.getElementById(pro).selected=true;


                }
        </script>
    </head>
```

Esta es la tabla donde mando a llamar mi metodo.

```
<%     
            out.println("<table border=1>"
                    + "<tr>"
                        + "<th>ID</th>"
                        + "<th>NOMBRE</th>"
                        + "<th>PRECIO</th>"
                        + "<th>PROVEEDOR</th>"
                    + "</tr>");                    

            for (Producto m:ar){
                out.println("<tr>"
                        + "<td>"+m.getIdproducto()+"</td>"
                        + "<td>"+m.getNombreproducto()+"</td>"
                        + "<td>"+m.getPrecio()+"</td>"
                        + "<td>"+m.getPro().getNombreprov()+"</td>"
                        + "<td>"
                        + "<a href=javascript:llenar('"+m.getIdproducto()+"','"+m.getNombreproducto()+"',"
                        + "'"+m.getPrecio()+"','"+m.getPro().getIdproveedor()+"')>Seleccionar</a>"
                        + "</td>"
                        + "</tr>");
            }
            out.println("</table>");

            }catch(Exception e){}
        %>
```

HTML de mi formulario

```
<tr>
                <td>ID:</td>
                <td><input type="text"  id="idd" name="id" readonly="readonly"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Nombre:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="nombree" name="nombre"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Precio:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="precioo" name="precio"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Proveedor:</td>
                <td>
                     <select id="provv" name="prov">
                           <%
                           for(Proveedor m:ar1){
                               out.println("<option id='"+m.getIdproveedor()
                                                    +"' value='"+m.getIdproveedor()
                                                    +"'>"+m.getNombreprov()+"</option>");
                                        }

                                    %>
                                </select>
                            </td>
            </tr>
```

Si en una de las clases lleva un dato con un espacio, no me agrega nada en ningun textbox.

Pero si en las clases que tienen valores String, y no tienen un espacio, si me los agrega en sus respectivos textbox.

¿Como puedo hacer para que me los agregue si pongo dos nombres dentro de una clase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cómo estás?

Intenta realizar lo siguiente:
La idea es reemplazar los espacios vacíos del string por " " por lo que puedes probar lo siguiente:

```
var text = 'Tu texto con espacios';
var result = text.replace(/ /g, "&nbsp;");
console.log(result); //Tu&nbsp;texto&nbsp;con&nbsp;espacios
```

Suerte!